# How to Find Bigger Number in Two Array Elements Compare

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two dynamic array which can be like

```
arr1 = [4, 17, 12, 11];
arr2 = [11, 10, 23, 11];
```

now I need to always save the bigger numbr on `#cal-box-1-1` and smaller on `#cal-box-1-2` to deduct smaller number from the bigger number

```
for (i = 1; i < arr1.length; i++) { 
   $(".map").append('<div class="mapper"><div id="cal-box-1-'+i+'"></div><div id="cal-box-1-'+i+'"></div></div>");
}
```

Comment: You have 2 arrays..you have not mentioned from which array you want to make manipulations ? I would go with `array-sorting` and would use **first** and **last** item from array after sorting..

Comment: For the lowest value: Instead of `max`, use `min`.

Comment: That in fact is the question! in simple math you cant do `arr1[1] -arr2[1]` because 10 is smaller than 17

Comment: so I need to dynamically find the bigger numbr and deduct it

Comment: This question is Totally different!

Comment: @Behseini: I noticed, re-opened the question.

Comment: This is in fact finding bigger number between two elements from two arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this code to determine which number is bigger or smaller:

```
for (i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) { // I assume you want to start with the first element
   var bigger = Math.max(arr1[i], arr2[i]);
   var smaller = Math.min(arr1[i], arr2[i]);
}
```

Comment: I do but I need to store values in div ids so I thoght may I should start with1

Comment: that's absolutely no problem

Comment: The way you are doing it, you miss the first element in both arrays because you are skipping element zero.

Answer (score 3):

If you always want to subtract the lower number from the highest number, you can do this:

```
var result = Math.abs(value1 - value2);
```

It doesn't matter which of the 2 is the highest value:

```
10 - 7 === 3;      // Correct order
Math.abs(3) === 3;  // Value doesn't change.

7 - 10 === -3;     // Wrong order,
Math.abs(-3) === 3; // But Math.Abs fixes that.

-7 - -10 === 3;    // Correct order (-10 is smaller than -7)
Math.abs(3) === 3;  // Value doesn't change.

-10 - -7 === -3;   // Wrong order,
Math.abs(-3) === 3; // But Math.Abs fixes that.
```

Because you'll always be subtracting the lowest value from the highest value, you will *always* get a result that's `>= 0`.

Comment: @Behseini: I added an example to show this also works for negative values.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking to find the largest number and the smallest number and then subtract the two?

```
Math.max(...arr1.concat(arr2)) - Math.min(...arr1.concat(arr2))
arr1.concat(arr2) => [10, 11, 11, 11, 12, 17, 23, 4]
Math.max(...arr1.concat(arr2)) => 23
Math.min(...arr1.concat(arr2)) => 4
```

Comment: The OP does not hint that he may be using ES6. You're also using quite a few "heavy" operations to do something that's quite simple.